# placement-new and 3rd party controlled allocations

Tags: c++, shared-memory, placement-new

I am trying to allocate a 3rd party class (not written by me) in shared memory segment.

Dont know how is implemented this class but it may contain another "new", "malloc" calls to allocate memory for its needs.

Does it mean that this new memory will not be allocated inside the shared memory segment and will use standard heap - as a result forked processes will cause segmentation fault accessing functions of this class?

Comment: Title is missleading + you could provide some code as well.

Comment: @LihO:  I had to read it a few times, but what I concluded was that this 3rd party class dynamically allocated it's own stuff.  The question is, if OP uses placement-new to instantiate the 3rd party class in to a static buffer, then will that other stuff be allocated in the static buffer as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that this new memory will not be allocated inside the shared memory segment and will use standard heap - as a result forked processes will cause segmentation fault accessing functions of this class?

Right.  If the other class allocates it's own stuff using `new`, then that stuff won't be in your placement-new buffer.

Comment: The caviate is if the other class overrides new, but that is unlikely.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams:  That's not a caveat.  Even if the 3rd party class (which OP has no control over and knows nothing of OP's code) overrides `new`, then that other 'stuff' still won't be placed in OP's buffer.

Comment: `struct AA{uint8_t* buff_; inline void* operator new(size_t size,void* buff) {const int buff_size = 10;AA* ret = (AA*)buff;AA* abuff = ret;uint8_t* buffs = (uint8_t*)(ret+sizeof(AA)); abuff->buff_ = buffs; return buff;}};` Absolutely uses the memory passed in, but is #1 weird and #2 very very unlikely :-/ In this case, it doesn't use "new" or "malloc" perse, just uses an alternate that would work.